# Bitrix Добавление пользовательских полей в раздел по-умолчанию

Tags: php, битрикс

Вообщем у меня есть такая проблема или лучше сказать идея, но я не могу как правильно её реализовать. Вообщем я хочу через обработчик

```
OnBeforeIBlockSectionAdd
```

Добавить массив пользовательских полей для раздела в форму редактирование, т.е. человек нажимает кнопку добавить раздел и в форму добавляется массив из заранее забитых пользовательских полей. Для того чтобы привязать св-во в разделу инфоблока идёт такой код:

```
$arFields = Array(
    "ENTITY_ID" => "IBLOCK_2_SECTION",
    "FIELD_NAME" => "UF_TITLE",
    "USER_TYPE_ID" => "string",
    "EDIT_FORM_LABEL" => Array("ru"=>"заголовок", "en"=>"title")
);
$obUserField  = new CUserTypeEntity;
$obUserField->Add($arFields);
```

Но как всё это связать в месте??
может кто-то уже такое делал.

Comment: а зачем через событие? немного непонятна суть, так как `OnBeforeIBlockSectionAdd` отрабатывает перед уже добавлением раздела, а не когда открывается страница Добавления раздела. А просто добавить пользовательское свойство для разделов типа список?

Comment: @maxkrasnov Разделов планируется много, очень много и для всех разделов одинаковые пользовательские поля, а задать заранее это нельзя, поэтому приходится придумывать подобные костыли.

Comment: можно сделать так: 1. Делаете свойство типа строка/список без разницы 2. Есть событие на построение админ таба, ну то есть, когда вы открываете страницу Добавления раздела (можно сделать проверку по урлу) вот ссылка на док https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onadmintabcontrolbegin.php, и там уже выводить какой-угодно список и записывать все в пользовательское свойство. Наверное кривовато объяснил, но может суть поймете

Comment: визуально генерируете нужный список, а записываете все в свое пользовательское свойство, так же по аналогии обрабатываете, если поле уже не пустое

Comment: @maxkrasnov Вот событие на построение админтаба в форме действительно годная идея, надо будет попробовать.

Comment: написал как ответ, если поможет то можно пометить как решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnBeforeIBlockSectionAdd` отрабатывает перед уже добавлением раздела, а не когда открывается страница Добавления раздела, поэтому рекомендую использовать для такой задачи событие построения админ. таба `OnAdminTabControlBegin`, ссылка на документацию: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onadmintabcontrolbegin.php

Таким образом можете генерировать динамически список и сохранять в пользовательское свойство